# dojo loader is appending 'main.js' to my packages

Tags: module, dojo, amd

For my packages, dojo seems to be appending 'main.js' to end of each file resulting in a '404' has any one experienced this and or have a solution?

```
GET http://localhost:9000/scripts/prodLayers/main.js 404 (Not Found)

var dojoConfig = {
            has: {
               "dojo-firebug": true,
               "dojo-debug-messages": true
            },
            tlmSiblingOfDojo: true,
            async: true,
            parseOnLoad: false,
            packages: [
                { name: "prod", location: "/scripts/prodLayers"}
            ]
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 packages: [    
   { name: "prodLayers", location: "/scripts/mylibs", main: "prodLayers"}
]
```

The "main" attribute is name of the file to be referenced using 'baseUrl' to define the package locations may also help to simplify the "location" params.